# Why I can't visualize in MyWorld Standard digital identity created with Insomnia workspace offered by Platform of Trust?

Tags: api, platform, ontology-network, platform-of-trust

I have created a small identity network using insomnia workspace as it described here https://developer.oftrust.net/guides/workflow-using-insomnia-workspace/ I have account on sandbox.

I have logged in MyWorld Standard App https://pot.dev.valaa.com:8078/ but the site says that it can’t find context.
[MyWorld Standard behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIVMR.png)

What is missing in order to see that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insomnia workspace with one click feature enhances possibility to create identity networks with context links from v2 standards (https://standards.oftrust.net/v2/ )

For the time being http://pot.dev.valaa.com/ supports only context links from v1 of standards (https://standards.oftrust.net/v1/ )

Comment: What benefits are there if using standard v2 instead of standards v1?
How should I decide which one to use for my application / identity network?